# F6 key issues error: Record file not found

Tags: probsoln

I try to press the F6 key and in the YouTube tutorials those who make the video pressing them all go well, but not me :(

Comment: If you're using TeXworks, click on the green button next to the drop-down menu with the formats, on the left of the status bar.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Your question is a bit unclear, maybe you can add some details? You can press the `edit` button at the bottom of the post to modify your question. Specifically: which editor do you use? What is the F6 key supposed to do? What does it do in your case, nothing at all or some error message? Can you give an example of a Youtube video where this key is used?

Comment: F6 is more common for Texmaker so it looks like attempting to following one you tube tutorial whist using a totally different editor (OR confusion as to the fact there is a difference in name)